# Using Swift 3, how do you make a UILabel text have a glow/growing animation?

Tags: animation, swift3, uilabel

How can I make label text do this (make the font get bigger, then smaller):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    myLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(35))
    // set font size which you want instead of 35
    myLabel.transform = myLabel.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.35, y: 0.35)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.myLabel.transform = self.myLabel.transform.scaledBy(x: 5, y: 5)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.myLabel.transform = self.myLabel.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.35, y: 0.35)
        })
    })
```

Comment: Can you show me how to implement it into a function maybe?

Comment: @NathanC I tried and its working...what is not working for you ?

Comment: @NathanC you could just put this code in a function and call it or add probably a boolean to repeat the animation.